# Копировать анимацию костей из одного проекта в другой

Tags: python, blender

Мне нужно скопировать анимацию с одной модели в другую, как это сделать в Blender ?

Comment: Теоретически надо выгрузить веса и индексы костей для каждого вертекса в меше, а также матрицу/кватернион для каждого ключевого кадра каждой кости в скелете.

Comment: о ужас, я конечно попробую, но не думаю что я и половины понял сказанного, где это все у блендере находится?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать из вопроса, если перенести скелет из одной сетки к другой вам придется заново делать оснастку и расстановку весов для вертексов новой сетки. 

Если вы имеете в виду экспорт геометрии то смотрите ответ выше и используйте справку внутри самого Blenderа.

Comment: Мне нужно полностью перенести движения из одного скелета на другой

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно скопировать только ключевые кадры, то это можно сделать в Graph Editor через Crtl+C/Ctlr+V. Но тут могут быть лишние заморочки с тем, что бы добавить для второго скелета такой же набор анимируемых элементов.

Другой вариант, как мне кажется проще - через Python Console вот такими командами:

```
a1 = bpy.data.objects['Armature1']
a2 = bpy.data.objects['Armature2']
a2.animation_data_create()
a2.animation_data.action = a1.animation_data.action.copy()
```

где 'Armature1' и 'Armature2' названия скелетов.

Если вы хотите не просто копию анимации, а иметь общую для двух скелетов анимацию, то последнюю строчку замените на:

```
a2.animation_data.action = a1.animation_data.action
```

Что бы это всё правильно сработало нужно, что бы названия костей обоих скелетов совпадали.